# Bounded weakly* convergent sequence in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with bounded limit ...(with the same limits)

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\left(a_{i}\right)_{i}$ be a sequence in $L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$ ($\Omega$ is a regular bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,$n=2,3$) and $c_{1},c_{2}$ be real numbers such that $c_{1}\leq a_{i}\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\leq c_{2}\text{ a.e. }\mathbf{x}\in\Omega$, for all $i$. If $a_{i}\stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup}a$ in the weak* topology $\sigma\left(L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right),L^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\right)$, for some fixed $a\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$, can we affirm that $c_{1}\leq a\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\leq c_{2}\text{ a.e. }\mathbf{x}\in\Omega$? I prove that it is valid for positive real numbers $c_{1},c_{2}$ (using the fact that every closed ball in the weak* topology is compact). But, the general case is complicated for me. Recall that $L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$ is the dual space of $L^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$. For more information of weak* topology see the book of Brezis.

thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

Weak* convergence implies that $\int a_i I_A \to \int a I_A$ for every Borel set $A$ in $\Omega$. This gives $c_1 m(A) \leq \int_A a  \leq c_2 m(A)$ and this in turn implies $c_1 \leq a \leq c_2$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Please, can you explain the final implication?

Comment: @Joshua Take $A=\{x: a(x) >c_2\}$. If this set has positive measure then $\int_A a(x)dx >\int_A c_2 dx=c_2 m(A)$ but this is  a contradiction. Hence $m(\{x: a(x) >c_2\}=0$ which means $a(x) \leq c_2$ a.e. Similarly $a(x) \geq c_1 $ a.e..